# Is multiplication by $n$ a closed map for an abelian topological group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, abelian-groups, topological-groups, closed-map

Let $G$ be an abelian topological group. Let $n$ be an integer and consider $G\to G$ given by sending $x\mapsto nx$.

Is this a closed map? I do not have any particular reason to think it should be, but it would make a certain step in something I am reading much easier, so I am curious about whether it is true or not.

It might be useful to assume that $G$ is Hausdorff and locally compact, but those might not be necessary.

Thanks for any help, direction, or insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not necessarily, even if $G$ is locally compact Hausdorff.  For instance, let $A$ be any infinite discrete abelian group where every element has order dividing $n$ (e.g., an infinite direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/n$) and let $G=A\times \mathbb{R}$.  Let $(a_k)$ be a sequence of distinct elements of $A$, and consider the set $C=\{(a_k,1/k):k\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset G$.  Then $C$ is closed, since the $a_n$ are all distinct.  But the image of $C$ under multiplication by $n$ is $\{(0,n/k:k\in\mathbb{N})\}$, which is not closed, because $(0,0)$ is in its closure.